# jquery tooltips not appearing when mouse is hovering over text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-tooltip

I'm following this [tutorial](http://3nhanced.com/javascript/simple-tooltip-powered-by-jquery/) to add a simple jquery tooltip. The tutorial uses three images to construct the tooltip background but I only want to use one. Right now I'm trying to make the tooltip appear when I hover over certain text. I don't know if I'm making a simple mistake or if the code doesn't make sense. Either way, the tooltip won't appear when I hover over the text.

Here is my version of the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toolTip').hover(
    function() {
    this.tip = this.title;
    $(this).append(
     '<div class="toolTipWrapper">'
        +'<div class="toolTipPic">'

          +this.tip
       +'</div></div>'
    );
    this.title = "";
    this.width = $(this).width();
    $(this).find('.toolTipWrapper').css({left:this.width-22})
    $('.toolTipWrapper').fadeIn(300);
  },
    function() {
      $('.toolTipWrapper').fadeOut(100);
      $(this).children().remove();
        this.title = this.tip;
      }
  );
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.toolTip {}
.toolTipWrapper {
        width: 175px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        display: none;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 9pt;
}
.toolTipPic {
        width: 175px;
        background: url(tooltip.png) no-repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="toolTip" title="This is the tooltip text">Hover over me for tooltip </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
$(this).find('.toolTipWrapper').css({left:this.width-22});
```

You setting the left property to the width of the p tag, but you haven't set a width on the p tag so its width is the whole width of the page. For example when I tired this it set left to '1247px' which was of to the side of the browser window.

Comment: I set a width of 100 for p but when I hover over the text I only see a tiny portion of the image I downloaded here http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: Beacuse you are using is as a css background in .toolTipPic, you need to have the width and height set to the size of the image.